# Match couples - Data mining/Texmining - Cluster - [help]

Tags: cluster-analysis, weka, data-mining, text-mining

I'm trying to do a system to match couples. A person must complete a form with age, country, hobbies, preference, sex with all of these data I'd like to know who's the best person to match with another person. I'll use clusters with WEKA so i need to know the best person to match with another person. I need some suggestions to do this. Someone knows some similar work to read, test or have any other ideas?

Thanks Greetings

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. Matchmaking needs much more psychology.

Also, clustering is the wrong tool. I guess your idea is to use *similarity search*. Whst do you need *groups* for? What would you do if your analysis reveals there id only one group in your data, or if there are clusters with 1 element only?